# TextReader.Read() not returning correct integer?

Tags: c#, file-io, int, textreader

So my method should in theory work, I'm just not getting my expected result back.

I have a function that creates a new TextReader class, reads in a character (int) from my text file and adds it too a list.

The textfile data looks like the following (48 x 30):

> 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111100000000001111111111000000111111111
>   111111110000000000000000000000000000000011111111
>   100000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111
>   000000000000001111111111111111111111000001111111
>   100000001111111111111111111112211221000001111111
>   100000111111122112211221122111111111000001111111
>   111111111221111111111111111112211110000011111111
>   111112211111111111111111111111111100000111221111
>   122111111111111122111100000000000000001111111111
>   111111111111111111100000000000000000011111111111
>   111111111111111111000000000000000001112211111111
>   111111111111221110000001111110000111111111111111
>   111111111111111100000111112211111122111111111111
>   111111112211110000001122111111221111111111111111
>   111122111111000000011111111111111111112211221111
>   111111110000000011111111112211111111111111111111
>   111111000000001111221111111111221122111100000011
>   111111000000011111111111000001111111110000000001
>   111111100000112211111100000000000000000000000001
>   111111110000111111100000000000000000000000000011
>   111111111000011100000000000000000000000011111111
>   111111111100000000000000111111111110001111111111
>   111111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

My method is as follows:

```
private void LoadReferenceMap(string FileName)
    {
        FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, FileName);
        List<int> ArrayMapValues = new List<int>();

            if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                // Create a new stream to write to the file
                using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(FileName))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
                        {
                            int x = reader.Read();

                            if (x == -1)
                                break;

                            ArrayMapValues.Add(x);
                        }
                    }
                }

                level.SetFieldMap(ArrayMapValues);
            }
    }
```

Returns:

[image]

As you can see once it reaches the end of the first line Read() returns 13 and then 10 before moving on to the next row?

Comment: This appears to be a Text file and a small one also. Then why don't you use the more simple approach of File.ReadLines or similar methods? Reading a string as a Char array is pretty simple.

Comment: "it appears to be faultless I'm just not getting my expected result back" - I do not think faultless means what you think it means... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different approach that removes both problems with conversion of chars to integers and the skipping of Environment.NewLine characters

```
private void LoadReferenceMap(string FileName)
{
    List<int> ArrayMapValues = new List<int>();

    if (File.Exists(FileName))
    {
        foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(FileName))
        {
            var lineMap = line.ToCharArray()
                              .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString()));
            ArrayMapValues.AddRange(lineMap);
        }
        level.SetFieldMap(ArrayMapValues);
    }
}
```

The file is small, so it seems to be convenient to read a line as a string (this removes the Environment.NewLine), process the line converting it to a char array and applying the conversion to integer for each char. Finally the List of integers of a single line could be added to your List of integers for all the file.

I have not inserted any check on the length of a single line (48 chars) and the total number of lines (30) because you say that every file has this format. However, adding a small check on the total lines loaded and their lengths, should be pretty simple.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for taking the time to rewrite my method and explain in further detail. I've tested it and it works in its method of removing the problem with the NewLine however it is still returning the ints the same. 49's for 1's etc?

Comment: Well if you want the conversion to the numbers 0,1,2 then you need to convert back the char to a string composed of a single char. Updating the answer

Comment: @steve: he wants the integer, not the `char` so there will need to be some `Integer.Parse` or similar going on too.

Comment: Yes but if we could be certain about the content of the file (only 0,1,2 or other single char representing a digit) then we could spare the Parsing and use directly the conversion without unnecessary checks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you need to convert the symbol you've got to the `char`, like this:

```
(char)sr.Read();
```

After that you can parse it as `int` with different approach, for example:

```
int.Parse(((char)sr.Read()).ToString());
```

[More information on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx).

> As you can see once it reaches the end of the first line Read() returns 13 and then 10 before moving on to the next row?

The line break in the .NET looks like this: `\r\n`, and not the `\n` (Check the [`Environment.NewLine`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline) property.

Answer (score 1):

The actual text file has line breaks in it. This means that once you have read the first 48 characters the next thing in the file is a line break. In this case it is a standard windows new line which is a Carriage Return (character 13) followed by a Line Feed (character 10).

You need to deal with these line breaks in your code somehow. My preferred way of doing this would be the method outlined by Steve above (using `File.ReadAllLines`). You could alternatively though just at the end of each of your sets of 48 character reads check for the 13/10 character combo. One thing of note though is that some systems just use Line Feed without the carriage return to indicate new lines. Depending on the source of these files you may need to code something to deal with possible different line breaks. Using `ReadAllLines` will let something else deal with this issue though as would using `reader.ReadLine()`

If you are also unsure why it is returning 49 instead of 1 then you need to understand about character encoding. The file is stored as bytes which are interpreted by the reading program. In this case you are reading out the values of the characters as integers (which is how .NET stores them internally). You need to convert this to a character. In this case you can just cast to char (ie `(char)x`). This will then return a char which is `'1'`. If you want this as an integer you would then need to use `Integer.Parse` to parse from text into an integer.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain that to me! I was severely hungover yesterday and didn't stand much chance of independently researching this but I was still aching to know why it wasn't working. +1

Comment: No problem. Others had fixed on code solutions but hadn't really given the reasoning behind why you needed to do this so thought I'd jump in for that. :) Hope its all making sense now. :)